# What are the differences between using "new" keyword and and not using it?

Tags: c#

What are the differences between this:

```
Class object1 = new Class();
```

and this:

```
Class object1;
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty certain that the first code is used to refer to a new object while the other is not. Even if that's the case I still don't know which one I should be using for my program. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well in the latter, you're not instantiating anything. The value of `object1` is `null`. If you want to use the object, you need to use `new` or reference it to an existing object.

Comment: Both of them declare a variable.  The first one also instantiates an object and assigns its reference to that variable.  As for which one you should use, I would think that would be self-evident from what you're writing.  It's not really clear what the actual problem is here.

Comment: @Fester in one first one no memory occupied on heap

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First one is creating a `new` instance of `Class` object.

Second one is just declaring the a variable of `Class` type. It will be uninitialized until you initialize it.

Note that your first example is doing the same as the second one, plus initializing it.

```
Class object1 = new Class();
```

Is short syntax for:

```
Class object1;
object1 = new Class();
```

Comment: This answer is the only one that is short and clear, so I don't see why people are downvoting you. Anyhow, I will be accepting this answer after my 5 minutes is over. Thank you!

Comment: "will be NULL" if it's a field. Will be uninitialized (and unusable) if it's a local.

Comment: Yes, bad choice of words

Answer (score 2):

```
Class object1 = new Class();
```

is the same as

```
Class object1; // declare variable
object1 = new Class(); // instantiate object and assign reference to variable
```

Answer (score 2):

`Class object1 = new Class();` creates a new instance of `Class` and assigns it to the `object1` variable.

`Class object1;` only declares the variable, but does not assign **any value** to it (not even null). You cannot use the variable e.g. perform a null check or pass it into another method until you assign a value to it.

```
Class object1;
// other code
object1 = new Class();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable `Class object1` you're just defining a place to put something, that will only take objects of that type. Initially it will be null.

When you use `new` you're actually creating the object.